# How do you reference your GUI without creating a new instance in java?

Tags: java, user-interface

Hi I am having a problem with my program and I can't find an answer. Basically I have tried hard and stackOverFlow is my last hope..... I think I understand the problem but don't know how to fix it.......

So I have a GUI which has a JCalendar on it. I want to create a new table in a weekly schedule database based on what the user selects. However when I send the date the user selected to the methods it resets the date back to the current date. I'm 99% sure this is because I am creating a new instance of the gui every time I run this method. (I have only been studying java for 2 and a half months by myself so I'm no master).

Anyway my question is how do I reference the method getSelectedDate in the gui without having to create a new instance of the gui????? I have looked at every tutorial etc I can find but nothing has helped me yet...........

Any advice suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated..... Thanks again......

```
public  void createSchedule() {


              try {
                 this.doConnect();

                 stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                SchedulerGUI gui = new SchedulerGUI();
                 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(gui.getSelectedDate());
                 int WeekNum = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
                 int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                 String DatabaseString = "CREATE TABLE " + Integer.toString(year) + "_week_" + Integer.toString(WeekNum) + " (PeriodNum INT DEFAULT 1  NOT NULL, Monday VARCHAR(30), Tuesday VARCHAR(30), Wednesday VARCHAR(30), Thursday VARCHAR(30), Friday VARCHAR(30), Saturday VARCHAR(30), Sunday VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY (PeriodNum))";
                 System.out.println(DatabaseString);

               // stmt.executeUpdate(DatabaseString); ------- I  have this //'d out so that I'm not creating a new table every time a new weeks starts. So I don't jump for joy thinking I've fixed it! :)


             } catch (SQLException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(Methods.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This schedule already exists. Please update it or select another week.");
             }   finally{


                 try {
                  con.close();
                    stmt.close();
                 } catch (SQLException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(Methods.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 }
```

Comment: You could pass a reference of the UI elements you need or better, have your method return a data structure you can wrap the required UI models around...

Comment: Pass the date you want to the method `public List<...> createSchedule(Date date) {` and return a `List` of values which represent the rows in the table (each element in the `List` would need to have the values for each column)

Comment: Why do you need to create a new table?  The point of the database is store like data, so you should already have a table, which has a column for the date information...

Comment: The program will allow the user to make a weekly timetable based on the year and week number. The problem I am having is that every time I want to access anything from the GUI I have to create a new instance of the gui which then resets the JCalendar which is located on the GUI form.

I need a way of accessing this user selected date without having to say SchedulerGUI gui = new SchedulerGUI();
and then saying gui.getSelectedDate....

because every time I do this no matter what date I select on the JCalendar when I click the button it's reset ted back to today's date...

Comment: Why not register a listener in you JCanlendar object to handle this? It is not a good pattern to access GUI from backend service.

Comment: Look, I might be missing context, but creating a new table for the year/week is just a bad idea.  You should have a table which already has a column for the year and week, which is indexed and you simply manage that table

Comment: So you say to register a listener and do all the work on the SchedulerGUI? Ideally I am looking to have all the work done on another class i.e methods. The idea was to mimimize the amount of code and workings actually done on the SchedulerGUI form.....

Comment: Decouple your code.  The UI "gets" the date, it passes that information to your `createSchedule` method.  This means that `createSchedule` could be called for any number of reasons, from any number of contexts and it doesn't care...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the context, but I believe that you are creating an instance of the Java object Calendar, which is not a GUI object.

Have you tried referencing your already existing JCalendar GUI object? It looks like you reference some sort of GUI, but I'm not too sure that that is the JCalendar.

Comment: *"which is not a GUI object"* but `SchedulerGUI gui = new SchedulerGUI();` probably is

Comment: Right, but I'm just wondering if the SchedulerGUI extends JCalendar, or if it's the container of the JCalendar.

Comment: gui is a reference of SchedulerGUI. I need to instantiate it so that I can use the functions on it i.e getSelectedDate..... However every time I do this it resets the JCalendar on the ScedulerGUI form back to today's current date which is not the date the user selects.......

The program allows the user to create timetables based on week numbers of the year....... e.g 2015_week_12...... However every time I select week 12 on the JCalendar and try send it to the methods it is reset ted to the current week

OSAbdel it is the container.......

Thank you for helping me btw........

Comment: Okay, I think your problem might be that you don't have a constant reference to your GUI, then.

Comment: If you are allowed, make the GUI global and just use that reference to getSelectedDate(), etc... You should have 1 reference to your GUI elements for the rest of your project.

Comment: *"If you are allowed, make the GUI global "* - NO, for the love of sanity NO.  The method should have NO concept of the UI AT ALL, ever.  The method should not care HOW the date is determine, only that it needs the date value.  Decouple the code so that it can run independently of each other!

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. If Seamus decides to go the route of Separation of Concerns, then I believe your answer should suffice.

Comment: Thank you OsAdbel and MadProgrammer. It's working fine now. As it's only one variable that needs to be global I took the date one. I took MadProgrammers advice on decoupling the code and OsAbdel's on making global variables.........

Thank you both very much..... You really solved a headache for me......

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance. Good luck in your future endeavors and May the Force be with you!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, the reference to `gui` should be a member of whatever class `createSchedule()` is a member of.  If the GUI creates this object, it could pass in a reference to itself.  Make sure it does this only after its constructor returns; otherwise you would be leaking `this` from the constructor, which is bad.

A more sophisticated way to do it would be to have the GUI pass in an instance of [SwingPropertyChangeSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/SwingPropertyChangeSupport.html).  Your program logic would pump property events into it, and the GUI would listen for them and update itself.

Comment: ...or just pass the `Date` to the `createSchedule`...decouples the code, reduces exposing portions of the code to each that don't need to know about each other...nice, clean and simple

Answer (score 0):

Very basically, change the `createSchedule` method so you are forced to pass the information it needs to it and it passes back information you need (if required)

```
public void createSchedule(Date date) {

    try (Connection con = doConnect()) {
        try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            int WeekNum = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            String DatabaseString = "CREATE TABLE " + Integer.toString(year) + "_week_" + Integer.toString(WeekNum) + " (PeriodNum INT DEFAULT 1  NOT NULL, Monday VARCHAR(30), Tuesday VARCHAR(30), Wednesday VARCHAR(30), Thursday VARCHAR(30), Friday VARCHAR(30), Saturday VARCHAR(30), Sunday VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY (PeriodNum))";
            stmt.executeUpdate(DatabaseString);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Methods.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This schedule already exists. Please update it or select another week.");
    }
```

Also, take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for a better way to handle you resource management